# How to protect your Computer and Resources from Monsoon season

Tags: cleaning

Well How do I protect my Computer from Monsoon Season. I just found out that in Monsoon season RAM and Motherboard gets slow and wet due to Moisture. Also my Keyboard becomes full of Fungus. How do I protect my CPU and other Resources.

Comment: this question is somewhat funny to those of us in dryer climates.  +1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another idea: Use [anti-moisture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desiccant) agents. Computer components often come packed with packs of [silica gel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silica_gel) inside the box. Silica gel absorbs moisture. I've seen people who used large amounts of it to keep moisture low.

Also, keep computer components clean! Especially keyboard, mouse and similar parts where dead skin cells and other waste products may accumulate. This way, you'll provide less breeding ground for bacteria and fungi.

Answer (score 7):

If you have an enclosed space where you use your computer, you could try using a [dehumidifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehumidifier). If it is able to handle the humidity levels, you'd be able to prevent mold and condensation from forming on your components.

I would also keep offsite data backups in case of total catastrophe.

Answer (score 2):

The most you can do according to my research is:

1. Use an Uninterrupted Power Supply (UPS) or surge protector.
2. Ensure that computer and accessories are well grounded.
3. Keep your computer and accessories clean from dust.
4. Backup your data, just in case.
5. Turn your computer off and unplug during a storm.
6. In case of power cuts, do not turn on the computer immediately after power has been restored.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best things to avoid moisture on components and mainboard is to let you computer always on.
Not sure if it will be sufficient, depending on the degree of humidity you have.